# QtCreator to VS2015 shortcuts

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, keyboard-shortcuts, qt-creator

Do you know if a plugin or whatever exist to change VS2015´s keyboards shortcuts to make it like QtCreator ?

Just switched QtCreator to VS2015 (C++ coding) and it´s quite difficult to be effective without all my favorite QtCreator shortcuts.

Comment: Tools > Customize > Keyboard.

Comment: Any "automatic" solution will be prefered, I know you can do it by editing all shortcut. I´m really looking for a plugin or whatever changing the VS shortcut behavior.